# jQuery event delegation html table issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue using jQuery event delegation on a html table.

My html table contains  a *click* button on each row which open an additional html window using jQuery. The event works to open the window however the close event does not.

*ps: I want to use jQuery event delegation as I add new row in my table after having already bound the above listener.*

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/811089/).

```js
$(".list").on("click", "[data-window-open]", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  var targeted_popup_class = $(this).attr('data-window-open');
  $('div[data-window="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]:first').toggle();

});

$(".list").on("click", "[data-window-close]", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if ($(".window").is(":visible")) {
    $(".window").hide();
  }

});
```

```css
.window {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="list">
  <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>more</th>
  </tr>

  <!-- Popup Window 1 -->
  <div class="window" data-window="1">
    Ryan Sanchez
    <a href="#" data-window-close="1">close</a>
  </div>
  <tr>
    <td>Ryan</td>
    <td><a href="#" data-window-open="1">click</a></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Popup Window 2 -->
  <div class="window" data-window="2">
    Pascal Reventon
    <a href="#" data-window-close="2">close</a>
  </div>
  <tr>
    <td>Pascal</td>
    <td><a href="#" data-window-open="2">click</a></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Your event delegation is targeting the same elements, overwriting one another, meaning that firstly, the "click" will be open, then that very same element will be close afterwards.

Comment: a div element cannot stay after a tr element. So you can move the div into a cell.

Answer (score 0):

Change the selectors of the handlers:

```
$("[data-window-open]").on("click", function(e)
```

And

```
$("[data-window-close]").on("click", function(e)
```

Comment: as I said in my post I want to use jQuery event delegation as add new rows with ajax. These selectors would not work with the added rows.

Comment: @casusbelli your question does not include any AJAX code or any attempts towards what you just described though? As of right now, it's just the open and close, and regardless of adding new rows, you'll still face the same issue as described in this answer with your selectors.

Comment: @casusbelli what you need to look into is AJAX and jQuery / JavaScript `append` in order to add new rows. Make sure that your selectors for each individual action becomes unique to that action.

Comment: If you need to register an event handler for a new row, you have to do it after adding that row to the list, don't you?

Comment: Oh, I have realized that the popup divs are rendered outside of the table so they will not be retrieved by the selector $(".list"). You need to enclose the divs with <tr><td><div popups></div></td></tr> but the appearence changes completely

Answer (score 0):

I made the close event as a function which is working with default and added rows.

```
$(".list").on("click","[data-window-open]", function(e)  
{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation(); 

    var targeted_popup_class = $(this).attr('data-window-open');
    $('div[data-window="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]:first').toggle(); 

    closeWindow();
}); 

function closeWindow()
{
    $("[data-window-close]").on("click", function(e)  
    {
    e.preventDefault();

    if($(".window").is(":visible"))
    {
        $(".window").hide();
    }  

    }); 
}
```